# My React Protected Rout is Rendering briefly THEN Redirecting, Preventable?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I want to Navigate in React from a Protected Route to a Public route **without** the Protected route being visible for a brief second prior to the Redirect.

**ProtectedRoute.jsx** - This works but I see the protected route flash by.

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useUserAuth()
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />
  }
  return children
};
```

Below does not work with **useEffect**. I've tried a variety of ways with this.

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useUserAuth()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      return <Navigate to="/login" />
    }
    return children
  }, [user])
};
```

Am I on the right track? Has anyone been able to figure this out?

- **Stack**
- react-router-dom
- firebase/auth

Comment: Can you share all the relevant code? What is `useUserAuth` hook doing that it is not returning the current `user` value immediately? If the user is authenticated and they are on a protected route, shouldn't the protected component be visible until the navigation action is processed? Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: This returns the current state of the user in firebase auth, so there can be a delay since it's checking either firebase or a cookie - `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)`

Comment: Right, so to answer my question regarding what the `useUserAuth` hook is doing that it is not returning the current `user` value immediately, what *is* the `useUserAuth` hook returning initially? Can you share all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? I'm also still understanding the issue as you describe it. If the user is authenticated, and they are on a protected route, what is the issue with seeing any protected route content? Is it rather that the front end *thinks* they are authenticated but they are unauthenticated in the backend, and thus, the content "blip"?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704109/8690857 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961859/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese Wow, that fixed it because the `null` value from returned from `onAuthStateChanged` and set in the `const [user, setUser] = useState({})` had to be changed to `const [user, setUser = useState()`

Comment: Also -- I found that with this Auth doing a type check on the user and adding a loading part works to fix all issues - https://github.com/JREAM/react-auth/blob/master/src/components/PrivateRoute.jsx#L9